# DevExpress Style ASP.NET Controls

Tags: asp.net, jquery, devexpress

How can i customize asp.net controls like devexpress did?

Here is some example, this is actually what i want to make:

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/EditModes.aspx

About this, any tutorial, any resource?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- buy their ASPx controls, then you get the source. But then you have the real thing and don't need to mimic it.
- on the page you linked, right click and view the source. As it is ASP.Net, the styles are stored on your machine, you just have to learn where to find them so you can examine them.

My understanding is that DevExpress have moved to using an HTTP handler to deliver their styles and perform optimisations with what is delivered. So look for requests to any `.axd` files.

Comment: Dont you have any idea about where can i find a tutorial. I searched custom gridview in asp.net but what i found is not necessary.

Comment: @pegasus - what you have to realise is that a grid control like DevExpress's is nothing magical, it is simply a bunch of HTML tables and divs, and whatever controls are inserted into the grid cells. This means you can apply styles and css rules like any other html control. The DevExpress one will be different to all the others, your best way to work out how they did it is not with some random tutorial but to study what they output to the page.